# Newcommand with optional argument and ifthenelse

Tags: macros

I would like to define a new command `comp` with two arguments where the second (and last) argument is optional, using 'ifthenelse'. I tried :

```
\newcommand{\comp}[2]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}%
    {{#1}^{c}}% if #2 is empty
    {#2 \backslash #1}% if #2 is not empty
}
```

but `\comp{Y}{X}` gives `Y\X` instead of `X\Y` as wanted and `\comp{Y}` gives `Y\` instead of the result of `Y^c` as wanted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Optional arguments are usually set first and specified in brackets `[]` rather than braces `{}`.

With your code, if you type `$\comp{Y}=Z$`, the second argument is taken to be `=`, because of how TeX decides what the argument to a command is. Indeed, with

```
\newcommand{\comp}[2]{...}
```

the *required* arguments are two.

In my opinion, the optional argument should be the first, so you read

```
\comp[X]{Y}        \comp{Y}
```

as “the complement in *X* of *Y*” or “the complement of *Y*” respectively.

How to define that?

```latex
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\comp}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2^c}{#1\setminus#2}}
```

or

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\comp}{om}{\IfNoValue{#1}{#2^c}{#1\setminus#2}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative version that checks if the code following the first parameter starts with an opening brace `{`. If so it treats it as a second argument, otherwise it assumes only one argument is given. However, as this makes the code less readable and maintainable, I do not really recommend its usage.

The implementation uses `\@ifnextchar` to test for the following character after grabbing the first parameter, and then switches to either of the two implementations `\comp@single` or `\comp@double`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\comp[1]{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\comp@double{#1}}{\comp@single{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\comp@single[1]{%
    {{#1}^{c}}%
}
\newcommand\comp@double[2]{%
    {#2 \backslash #1}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\comp{Y}{X}$\par
$\comp{Y}$

\end{document}
```

outputs

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

An answer without `ifthen` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\comp}[2][]{%
\def\FirstArg{#1}
  \ifx\FirstArg\empty
    \ensuremath{{#2}^{c}}% if #1 is empty
    \else
    \ensuremath{#2 \backslash #1}% if #2 is not empty
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

$X\backslash Y$=\comp[Y]{X}

${Y}^{C}$=\comp{Y}
\end{document}
```

An answer with `ifthen`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\comp}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
    {\ensuremath{{#2}^{c}}}% if #1 is empty
    {\ensuremath{#2 \backslash #1}}% if #2 is not empty
}
\begin{document}

$X\backslash Y$=\comp[Y]{X}

${Y}^{C}$=\comp{Y}
\end{document}
```

Explaining:

A command has a defined number of arguments. If the arguments are mandatory (let's say 4) you have to define it like:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[4]{<Do things>}
```

If it has an optional argument {like in your case} it has to be the first one and (in case of 3 mandatory and an optional) you have to define it like:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[4][<First Argument Default Value>]{<Do things>}
```

The rest is the usage in your case (feel free to ask for anything not clear to you.).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're suggesting `$X\backslash Y$=\comp[Y]{X}` which is wrong under semantic and typographic points of view.

Comment: @egreg ... it is not my code ... It is op's code ... But still I am not sure about what exactly you mean here.

Comment: OP's code? I see nothing similar to `\ensuremath` in the OP's code. The syntax you're suggesting, namely `$Z$=\comp[Y]{X}` is really wrong, not because of the order of the arguments (which is wrong as well), but semantically: that should be a *single* formula.

Comment: @egreg ... I just added `\ensuremath` because OP ... talked about "`\comp{Y}{X}`" and not "`$\comp{Y}{X}$`" ... So, I thought it will be useful to him/her. This is why I just tested the command out of the math environment too. But thanks anyway for your comments ... Sure will help future visitors.  PS: The part inside the `document` environment is just a test to show that this produces the desired order etc ... Not a typographic suggestion.